# Check that multiple row exist in a list

Tags: django, python-2.7

I want to check whether `request.user.id` and `profiles.profile_id` exist in `block_lists_with_id`. And I am new to django. So if the question is not correct, somebody please help me to correct the question.

**Models.py**

```
class profiles(models.Model):
    profile_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    -----
class Block_list(models.Model):
    who = models.ForeignKey(User)
    whose = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
def view_profiles(request):
    block_lists_with_id = Block_list.objects.values_list('who_id', 'whose')
    return render_to_response('profiles/all.html', {'block_lists_with_id':block_lists_with_id}, context_instance=RequestContext(request),)
```

**Template**

I don't know the given template is in proper way or not. But I want this type of checking. So somebody please suggest me a proper way.

```
{%if request.user.id and profiles.profile_id in block_lists_with_id %}
   done
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for my question.I changed this 
 `block_lists_with_id=Block_list.objects.values_list('who_id', 'whose')`    to

```
block_lists_with_id = Block_list.objects.filter(who_id = user_id).values_list('whose', flat=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def view_profiles(request):
    block_lists_with_id = Block_list.objects.filter(who_id = user_id).values_list('whose', flat=True) 
    return render_to_response('profiles/all.html', {'block_lists_with_id':block_lists_with_id}, context_instance=RequestContext(request),)
```

**template**

```
{% if profile.user_id in block_lists_with_id %}
 done
{% endif %}
```

Comment: if anyone want to clarify the question please ask